# Default back button navigation animation in Android

Tags: android

I'm wanting to make "up" navigation use the same animation as "back" navigation. I'm using `overridePendingTransition` to override the animation, but I can't figure out which animation resource the back button uses by default. Does anyone know?

As an example, in a default ICS installation, the Settings app does this from its sub-pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up calling `finish()` on up navigation. That way, the animation is the same and the previous activity doesn't lose its state. For reference, the code looks like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Note that if your activity could be started from outside your app, some additional logic may be needed to ensure that up navigation behaves as expected.

Comment: Why don't you just setup ancestral navigation? https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html Won't that use the same animation as back button (regardless of what animation different versions use)?

Answer (score 1):

So, if I understand you correctly, you want to copy the "back" animation (slide out left) for one of your views or for overriding back button press. Well, to do this, create a new folder in your `res` folder named `anim`. Within the `anim` folder create a new `Android XML` file and call it `slide_out_left` and place the following code:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="-50%p"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
<alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>
```

Now, create another `Android XML` file and call it `slide_in_right` and place the following code:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate android:fromXDelta="50%p" android:toXDelta="0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
<alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>
```

Finally, you can call the animations wherever they are needed. For instance, while overriding the pending transition:

```
MyActivity.this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
```

Comment: The default ICS animation for the back button doesn't move sideways. It fades in and out in a 3d fashion.